# exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH when running golangcli-lint

Tags: go

I'm using `golangcli-lint` for my projects. But, when I run it using `golangcli-lint run`, it throws this error

```bash
ERRO Running error: context loading failed: failed to load packages: failed to load with go/packages: err: exit status 1: stderr: go: github.com/personal/private-repo@v1.5.4-staging.0.20221037132524-fa474c90e736: git init --bare in /home/personal/snap/golangci-lint/104/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/0478a3848f1237177112e0218abaefe19791c78a4f537df39ac0804ae69a3a05: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
go: github.com/personal/private-repo@v1.5.4-staging.0.20221037132524-fa474c90e736: git init --bare in /home/koinworks/snap/golangci-lint/104/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/0478a3848f1237177112e0218abaefe19791c78a4f537df39ac0804ae69a3a05: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
```

What happens here? I googled it, but they told me to install git because it's not installed. But I've been using this laptop for coding and using git & github for years with countless commits without any problem.

I use Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: have you install git? `apt-get install git`

Comment: Please verify if `git` is installed with `git --version`.

Comment: `git --version` is v2.25.1. Like I said, this same machine has produced more than 500 commits since last year. So, I'm not sure if installation is the problem.

Comment: @newline: That's strange. Did you try to reinstall `golangci-lint` to verify if its installation was fine?

Comment: @Azeem yes, already reinstalled and `golangcli-lint --version` shows me this `golangci-lint has version 1.50.1 built from 8926a95f on 2022-10-22T11:16:14Z`